# Extract dates from a string in php

Tags: php

I need to extract dates from a string: For example the string is  "...period from 06/01/2014 to 06/30/2014". How can I extract these two dates as:

```
$date1 = "06/01/2014"; 
$date2="06/30/2014";
```

Comment: With code. Where's yours?

Comment: is this the only date format you want to suppport?

Comment: only "dd/mm/yyyy" format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this

```
$string = "period from 06/01/2014 to 06/30/2014";

$results = array();

preg_match_all('#\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}#', $string, $results);

$date1 = $results[0][0];
$date2 = $results[0][1];
```

Comment: Interesting for when I did print_r($results) I found more than I expected to see - two rows containing arrays of the same pair of values.

Comment: @Grzegorz i removed the group `(...)` and now it's ok

Answer (score 0):

A Regular Expression is your best bet.

```
<?php
$string = "period from 06/01/2014 to 06/30/2014";

$pattern = "/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})/";

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

$date1 = $matches[0][0];
$date2 = $matches[0][1];

echo "Date1: " . $date1 . "<br />";
echo "Date2: " . $date2;
```

Outputs:

```
Date1: 06/01/2014
Date2: 06/30/2014
```