# Get date in a string php

Tags: php, regex

I want to get a date in a string in php and convert this date to other format:

> eg: today is 02/03/2016

```
$string = preg_replace('~(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2,4})~', '', $string);
```

but it is only erasing the date. it will print:

> today is

after get the date I want to change to other format:

```
$date = new DateTime($string);
$result = $date->format('F d, Y');
```

but, how to get only the date in the string? without erase it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = 'today is 02/03/2016';
$string = preg_match('/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/', $string, $date);
$date = new DateTime($date[0]);
$result = $date->format('F d, Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use date_format

```
$date = date('Y-M-D');
$new-date = date_format($date,'F jS Y');
echo $new-date;
```

Outputs July 24th 2016

Comment: I want to get the date insite a string. for example: 02/03/2016 and replace it to February 02, 2016 .

Answer (score 0):

Method $date already gives it back in string.`$date = date("D M d, Y G:i");`  Now you have date string that you can use

Comment: I want to get the date insite a string. for example: 02/03/2016 and replace it to February 02, 2016

Comment: Im sorry then i dont know. I know only basics of php.